# read line by line from text file but no repeat with bash

Tags: bash

1,bash content:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/zjhxmjl/Desktop/111"
while read -r line;do
    sed "s/$/$line/" xiaoxiequanpin.lst >> quanpin_8shenri
    sed -i 's/ //g' quanpin_8shenri
    tr -d '\r'< quanpin_8shenri > quanpin_8shenri.new
    tr -s ' '< quanpin_8shenri.new > quanpin_8shenri.newest
    mv quanpin_8shenri.newest quanpin_8shenri.lst
done <"$file"
```

2,file "111"（location /home/zjhxmjl/Desktop/） content:

```
19800101
19800102
```

3,xiaoxiequanpin.lst content:

```
aaa
bbb
```

4,file "quanpin_8shenri.lst" result:

```
aaa19800101
bbb19800101
aaa19800101
bbb19800101
aaa19800102
bbb19800102
```

5,i want to result:

```
aaa19800101
bbb19800101
aaa19800102
bbb19800102
```

So someone can give me some advance?

Comment: You're *appending* to `quanpin_8shenri` -- did it have some content before your script started?

Comment: The `tr -s ' '` call is useless since the `sed` call removes all spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the result to sort and uniq:

```
someprocess | sort | uniq
```

EDIT

or simply:

```
someprocess | sort -u
```